# An animated series or a full-length film about teenagers who possess superpowers

Tags: story-identification, tv, cartoon, animation, super-hero

An animated series or a full-length film about teenagers who possess superpowers. They weren't typical Marvel or DC heroes.

I remember there was a boy who had yellowish green skin with growths, as if he was half a reptile or an alien. He also had a mother, she was an ordinary person. Besides them, I remember a guy who could control the fluids in the pipes. They were all sailing on a ship to an unknown destination, but the bottom line was that they seemed to be being held there as hostages or something.

I'm not sure that the whole series was dedicated only to these characters, perhaps they only appeared in one episode. I watched this series somewhere in 2006-2009, but I don't remember the channel. The animation style was somewhat similar to the animated series "Wolverine and the X-Men" in 2009, BUT I can't be completely sure of this, because childhood memories still idealize the works of the past.

Comment: Does https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h279a8-qvUs look familiar?